# Error uploading images (but the images are at the server!)

Tags: uploads, images

I have a huge problem with images with a size greater 1MB in my website and I really need some help.

If I try to upload an image with a size greater 1MB in my Media Library I get a generic error without any info: **"An error ocurred in the upload. Please try again later"**

The surprising thing is that if I go to the "uploads" directory through my FTP, the image is there! But I can't work with it from WordPress!

I already try (without success) to:

- Set *upload_max_filesize = 40M* at php.ini
- Deactivate all my plugins
- Changing my theme from a default one
- Set at .htacccess: *RLimitMEM max*
- Put at wp-config.php: *define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '93M');*

This is my [phpinfo()](http://www.favgijon.com/php.php). Any help to solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this plugin, it seems that it's a problem related with memory in 1&1 hosting: https://schnurpsel.de/wordpress-plugins/123-image-resize/